# Firebase oAuth: scope

Tags: firebase-authentication

How can I access or get the permission of the extended scopes provided by the third party identity authorizers like Google or Facebook?

Like, accessing the contacts from Facebook or Google+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Facebook you should ask for the permissions that you want to get from the user. For example `read_custom_friendlists` permission will grant you access to the user Facebook friend's list. You can request the permissions using the Facebook SDK and integrating it in your app:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    // If using in a fragment
    loginButton.setFragment(this);    
    // Other app specific specialization

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });    
}
```

With `loginButton.setReadPermissions("email")` you are getting the permission to access to the email of the user. You can check all the permissions that you can get from [Facebook developers website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions).

About Google+, if I'm not wrong you should just use the android sdk to pick contacts from gmail.

hope that it will help you!